# Default Vuex project, return this.$store.state error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, this, vetur

Full error on `return this.$store.state.counter`:

Property '$store' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, { counter(): any; }, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, ... 7 more ..., {}>'.Vetur(2339)

Property '$store' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, OptionTypesType<{}, ... 4 more ..., {}>, ... 5 more ..., {}>'.Vetur(2339)

This is a clean Vue project (vue create v-vuex) with the following CLI configuration:

- Vue 3.x (Preview)
- **No** class-style component syntax
- **Yes** to Babel alongside TypeScript
- **ESLint + Prettier** linter and formatter
- Lint on save
- Dedicated config files

All files are **default files** created through Vue CLI with **default project structure**.

index.ts file:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    counter: 8,
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <h2>{{ counter }}</h2>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  computed: {
    counter() {
      return this.$store.state.counter;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

main.ts file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).mount("#app");
```

I am learning Vue and I want to access Vuex store state property. Basic counter example.

I can access the counter state only if I directly use it through the interpolation in the template such as `{{ $store.state.counter }}`, but as soon I want to use a computed property, which gives a return, I cannot access the $store with the keyword **this**.

`return this.$store.state.counter` does not work

My coding setup:

- VSCode, latest version
- NPM and Vue CLI
- Vetur
- ESLint
- Prettier

I have done the same example in different project setups, such as "no TypeScript" and "using Class-Style component syntax", but in the former case, my Vetur then does not work so it's not acceptable (not sure if it would error), and in the latter case, it works, but I am unfamiliar with the syntax, and as I am not experienced, it's overwhelming to even think about learning class-style to solve this issue.

Edit: There are similar questions, but none are related to a fresh Vue CLI project.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
export default createStore({
  state() {
    return : {
      counter: 8,
    }
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

```
counter: function () {
  return this.$store.state.counter;
},
```

working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ionic-vuex-forked-w571p?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: This does not work and creates more errors in the IDE.

Comment: this code works fine for me with no issues? where is the sample project so I can take a look... I edited my answer with link to code